# Swipe to dismiss demo animation on first screen open

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using Flutter Swipe to dismiss widget List

I want to show a small animation only for the first item to show as a demo only on the first time the page is opened,
how to create the demo animation for the first swipeable card.

is using widgettester to show this animation a good idea in a production application?